# Adding milliseconds to a DateTime in TSQL INSERT INTO

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm doing an INSERT INTO query in order to initialize a new table.
The primary key is RFQ_ID and Action_Time

How could add 1 millisecond to each Action_Time on a new record in order to avoid "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint"

```
INSERT INTO QSW_RFQ_Log
            (RFQ_ID, Action_Time, Quote_ID)
SELECT     RFQ_ID, GETDATE() AS Action_Time,  Quote_ID, 'Added to RFQ on Initialization' AS Note
FROM         QSW_Quote
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the real problem is that `RFQ_ID, Action_Time` shouldn't be a primary key. Create a [surrogate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) primary key and put a non-unique index on `RFQ_ID, Action_Time`.

**Update**: If you really want to stick with your existing design you could do what you asked but using 10 milliseconds instead of one millisecond between each row, to compensate for the low precision of datetime. You can use the row number to determine how many milliseconds to add so that you get a different timestamp for each row:

```
INSERT INTO QSW_RFQ_Log
(RFQ_ID, Action_Time, Quote_ID, Note)
SELECT
  RFQ_ID,
  DATEADD(millisecond, 10 * ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Quote_ID), GETDATE()) AS Action_Time,
  Quote_ID,
  'Added to RFQ on Initialization' AS Note
FROM QSW_Quote
```

Comment: +1 - Added some extra comments on other gotchas to watch out for as an answer, if this approach can't be taken

Answer (score 10):

I'd agree with Mark Byers' answer as the real solution. Just wanted to add a gotcha, that prior to SQL Server 2008, the datetime accuracy is to about 3.33ms. [Quote from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819(SQL.90).aspx):

> datetime values are rounded to
>   increments of .000, .003, or .007
>   second...

So adding 1ms to dates will not solve your problem.

e.g.

```
SELECT DATEADD(ms, 1, '2010-04-12T12:00:00.000') -- outputs time still as x.000s
SELECT DATEADD(ms, 2, '2010-04-12T12:00:00.000') -- output: .003s
SELECT DATEADD(ms, 3, '2010-04-12T12:00:00.000') -- output: .003s
SELECT DATEADD(ms, 4, '2010-04-12T12:00:00.000') -- output: .003s
SELECT DATEADD(ms, 5, '2010-04-12T12:00:00.000') -- output: .007s
SELECT DATEADD(ms, 6, '2010-04-12T12:00:00.000') -- output: .007s
SELECT DATEADD(ms, 7, '2010-04-12T12:00:00.000') -- output: .007s
SELECT DATEADD(ms, 8, '2010-04-12T12:00:00.000') -- output: .007s
SELECT DATEADD(ms, 9, '2010-04-12T12:00:00.000') -- output: .010s
```

You'd actually be needed to add 3ms each time. At best it would work for your situation, but just not really be what feels like a "clean" solution, a bit of hack. At worst, it just wouldn't work/scale, depending on the data volumes/the density of the data spread. But, you should be aware of the datetime accuracy gotcha if you head down this route.

SQL Server 2008 does introduce [DATETIME2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) which has an accuracy of 100ns. See DaveK's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx), although having re-read your question I'm not entirely sure why you are encountering that problem if you are inserting single rows at a time (and, as others have pointed out, the real issue seems to be your PK):

```
DECLARE @datetime2 datetime2 = '2007-01-01 13:10:10.1111111'
SELECT '1 millisecond' ,DATEADD(millisecond,1,@datetime2)
UNION ALL
SELECT '2 milliseconds', DATEADD(millisecond,2,@datetime2)
UNION ALL
SELECT '1 microsecond', DATEADD(microsecond,1,@datetime2)
UNION ALL
SELECT '2 microseconds', DATEADD(microsecond,2,@datetime2)
UNION ALL
SELECT '49 nanoseconds', DATEADD(nanosecond,49,@datetime2)
UNION ALL
SELECT '50 nanoseconds', DATEADD(nanosecond,50,@datetime2)
UNION ALL
SELECT '150 nanoseconds', DATEADD(nanosecond,150,@datetime2);
/*
Returns:
1 millisecond     2007-01-01 13:10:10.1121111
2 milliseconds    2007-01-01 13:10:10.1131111
1 microsecond     2007-01-01 13:10:10.1111121
2 microseconds    2007-01-01 13:10:10.1111131
49 nanoseconds    2007-01-01 13:10:10.1111111
50 nanoseconds    2007-01-01 13:10:10.1111112
150 nanoseconds   2007-01-01 13:10:10.1111113
*/
```

Comment: It's worth noting this is for SQL Server 2008 (which introduces DATETIME2 + nanosecond arg)

Answer (score 2):

**ever heard of "robing Peter to pay Paul"?**

you can manipulate the time, which is a real hack, to get the insert to work, but what about any concurrent inserts, they will have overlapping times.  Perhaps this will never happen based on your design, but I've learned over the years to never say never.

This is the exact reason why I never make a datetime a PK, they are not always unique.

> I need action time as a primary key,
>   period.

WHY?

You can make an identity be the PK and still have the clustered index on `RFQ_ID+Action_Time+identity` and how would that really affect your design or any performance?  it would also better reflect that the data was added simultaneously (each row with the same datetime)

Comment: well, I don't mind to do a "hack" because it's a one time query. I create the new table and initialize it using data from another table. Then, there will be only 2 or 3 records added by days. So, I could live with datetime in the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested above, use `DateAdd()` function, as:

```
INSERT QSW_RFQ_Log  (RFQ_ID, Action_Time, Quote_ID) 
SELECT RFQ_ID, DateAdd(ms, 1, GETDATE()) Action_Time,  
Quote_ID, 'Added to RFQ on Initialization' AS Note 
FROM QSW_Quote
```

But yr insert statement lists only three fields to be inserted into, but has four values to be inserted, so there's another problem there...

Comment: I fix the "three fields to be inserted into" error, there's in fact a dozen, but i cut that out for visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Adding only 1 millisecond wont work as the datetime values in SQL are rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 second. SO if you are going to add only 1 millisecond in any date time value there shall not be any impact on the original datetime.

You need to add minimum 2 milliseconds in the datetime so that the new datetime can be rounded to .003 and your implemnentations will work.