# How can I add exactly 1 millisecond?

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
select getdate(),DATEADD(millisecond,1,getdate())
```

yields me same answer....How to add exactly 1 millisecond?

I cannot use a `datetime2` field.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding miliseconds to a datetime in tsql INSERT INTO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625178/adding-miliseconds-to-a-datetime-in-tsql-insert-into)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380109/precision-of-sql-getdate

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to store milliseconds separately if you need that much accuracy. In SQL Server 2005 there is no native date/time type that will allow you to be more precise than ~3 ms. This is why, for example, the last time you can have in a day is 23:59:59.997, not .998 or .999.

Answer (score 6):

You can't. The accuracy of `datetime` is 3.33 milliseconds.

[Date and Time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The resolution of the `DATETIME` type is insufficient for your needs; per [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx), it is:

> Rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't, because `DateTime`s are represented as floating point number internally and 1 millisecond can not be represented as a `float`.

Please refer to the answers [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625178/adding-miliseconds-to-a-datetime-in-tsql-insert-into) for details.

Comment: Indeed you can't but not for the reason given exactly. SQL Server stores `datetime` as 2 integers, one for datepart and one for time. The time is stored as `ticks` with each tick being `1/300` of a second so it's just to do with the internal representation rather than anything to do with `float`